# install of 14.04.03 cause kernel panic before boot complete

Tags: system-installation, kernel

I have just re-installed 14.04.04 LTS for perhaps the fifteenth time. I have had much tro
uble getting it to install and have played around with formatting and partitions quite a bit. 
here is the output from   lsblk -f

[image]

boot-repair BootInfo summary:     http://paste.ubuntu.com/14410873/

here is the screen shot of the last thing i see after it stops booting

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the end it was the fact that I used a Sandisk Cruzer Blade USB drive and the pendrivelinuxtool. So I tried again with a different USB drive (LEXAR) and an different usb iso maker (Lili USB creator).

The difference was remakarkable and instant. Just using the USB was much slower in booting and running but did show a different menu than before to choose between installing or just trying Ubuntu. In the end I worked out I had 2 versions of grub each on a different partition. In gparted I had my HD showing up as 3 seperate drives and couldn't do anything about it. Luckily the installer was able to fix the lot.

I owe it all to [Can't run a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.10, shows kernel panic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/544419/cant-run-a-fresh-install-of-ubuntu-14-10-shows-kernel-panic)

which contained    http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2220625.html

Comment: you should accept your answer, sign of which is under vote down icon of your answer